# Infer the generic type parameter for a child component directly from the parent component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

How can I infer the generic type parameter for a child component directly from the parent component without explicitly passing it? Is that even possible?

What i got working is this. And MyType can be of any type but with the same structure.

```
export type MyType = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
};

<ParentComponent>
    {/* is ok */}
    <MyChildComponent<MyType> name="firstname"></MyChildComponent> 
    {/* this gives error */}``
    <MyChildComponent<MyType> name="test"></MyChildComponent> 
</ParentComponent>
```

But i would like this to work, byt only passing MyType to the parent. I'm not sure its possible. Below im only passing MyType to parent.

```
<ParentComponent<MyType>>
    {/* is ok */}
    <MyChildComponent name="firstname"></MyChildComponent> 
    {/* should give error */}
    <MyChildComponent name="test"></MyChildComponent> 
</ParentComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible, check github thread: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21699

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).